# looking for a word: "A certain fact can be ___ to another fact" (fact 2 is the cause of fact 1)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm struggling to find a word that can fit in this sentance:
"This difference can be ___ to the difference in methods".
Something *like* attributed, but not quite.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you volunteer that *attribute* is close, but you still reject it, the obvious course is to look up synonyms. Have you tried that?

Comment: *Fact B is **consequential** to fact A*. I doubt there's a specific verb that means *described as consequential*.

Comment: Why ‘not quite like _attributed_’? What’s wrong with _attributed_? It’s exactly the word to use …

Comment: Synonyms are ascribed / put down to.

Comment: FF makes a valid point. Perhaps you're looking for 'B is predicated on A', which states the functionality without using a modal (informing us that there is attribution / judgement going on) hedge.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, there are two ways to formulate that sentence. Given:

> (This difference)(A) can be ___ to (the difference in methods)(B)

, where A might happen because of B, then you can say:

> This difference can be **due** to the difference in methods

or

> This difference can be **caused by** the difference in methods

Answer (score 1):

*This difference is a **consequence** of the difference in methods.*

Answer (score 0):

This difference can be **attributed** to the difference in methods.

Comment: OP gives this (and discounts it).

Comment: My bad.  I didn't read closely enough.  There really isn't a better word that is idiomatic with "to."  Let's see what 128788 picks.